Английский текст в сообщении о дубликате
Отметил сегодня как дубликат следующий вопрос: Что значат эти скобки <> в Java?, но по какой-то причине поясняющее сообщение вывелось на английском языке:

This question is similar to: Ньюанс по дженерикам. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


This question is similar to: Не переведён новый комментарий о дубликате вопроса. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@andreymal прелестно, на мете та же проблема ))

Так на мете тот же код, что и на основном сайте в этой части.
